How can I move columns and the relative data inside a dataframe?
I have a dataframe like this:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['1.1', '1.2','1.3'],
    'C': [4.1, 5.2, 6.3]
})
print(df)

And I need to move the 'c' column under the 'a' column with a space in the middle.
I tried with the shif function, but it will move only the data under the column and not the column too. The dataframe I'm working on is bigger, so I need to move like 7 columns and data under the first 2 columns. Is that possible?

what is your expected output

updated answer: writing to Excel
What you want is not possible in pure pandas (well you could use a row as intermediate header, but it really doesn't make sense). However you can easily to this to an excel file. I've provided a similar answer here which can easily be adapted to this use case:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'B': [4, 3, 2, 1],
    'C': 'X', 'D': 'Y',
    'E': 'Y', 'F': 'Y',
})
print(df)

start = 0
gap = 1

groups = [['A', 'B'], ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F']]

with pd.ExcelWriter('outfile.xlsx') as writer:
    for g in groups:
        df.to_excel(writer, startrow=start, index=False)
        start += len(df)+df.columns.nlevels+gap

Output:

original answer
IIUC, you can select the desired columns and concat:
out = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['C']),
                 df['C'].rename('A')]
               ).reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
     A    B
0  1.0  1.1
1  2.0  1.2
2  3.0  1.3
3  4.1  NaN
4  5.2  NaN
5  6.3  NaN

If you want a "space" (= blank/NaN row) in between:
out = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=['C']),
                 pd.DataFrame(index=[0]),
                 df['C'].rename('A')]
               ).reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
     A    B
0  1.0  1.1
1  2.0  1.2
2  3.0  1.3
3  NaN  NaN
4  4.1  NaN
5  5.2  NaN
6  6.3  NaN

generalization to many columns
Using a loop:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['1.1', '1.2','1.3'],
    'C': [4.1, 5.2, 6.3],
    'D': [7.1, 8.2, 9.3],
    'E': [10.1, 11.1, 12.1]
})

below_A = ['C', 'D', 'E']

out = pd.concat([df.drop(columns=below_A)]+
                [df[below_A[i//2]].rename('A')
                 if i%2 else pd.DataFrame(index=[0])
                 for i in range(len(below_A)*2)]
               ).reset_index(drop=True)

Output:
       A    B
0    1.0  1.1
1    2.0  1.2
2    3.0  1.3
3    NaN  NaN
4    4.1  NaN
5    5.2  NaN
6    6.3  NaN
7    NaN  NaN
8    7.1  NaN
9    8.2  NaN
10   9.3  NaN
11   NaN  NaN
12  10.1  NaN
13  11.1  NaN
14  12.1  NaN

You could also try to melt:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1, 2, 3],
    'B': ['1.1', '1.2','1.3'],
    'C': [4.1, 5.2, 6.3],
    'D': [7.1, 8.2, 9.3],
    'E': [10.1, 11.1, 12.1]
})

keep = ['B']

out = (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(index=[0])], ignore_index=True)
         .melt(keep).rename(columns={'value': 'A'}).head(-1)
         .assign(variable=lambda x: pd.factorize(x['variable'])[0]==0)
         .assign(**{c: lambda x: x[c].where(x['variable'])
                    for c in keep})
         .drop(columns='variable')
      )

Output:
      B     A
0   1.1   1.0
1   1.2   2.0
2   1.3   3.0
3   NaN   NaN
4   NaN   4.1
5   NaN   5.2
6   NaN   6.3
7   NaN   NaN
8   NaN   7.1
9   NaN   8.2
10  NaN   9.3
11  NaN   NaN
12  NaN  10.1
13  NaN  11.1
14  NaN  12.1

